# include angular in google script

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-apps-script

I'm trying to code on google script an application with Angular,
so I declared angular on my HTML file(and it works), but, my .gs file doesn't understands angular functions.

my HTML (that works well)

```
<html ng-app="gemStore">
 <head>
      <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="main.gs"></script> 
 </head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

and my java file that doesn't recognises angular library

```
(function() {
 var app = angular.module('gemStore', []);

 app.controller('StoreController', function(){
 this.product = gems;
 });

var gems = 
{ name: 'Azurite', price: 2.95 }
;
})();
```

in my java file, I have an error "ReferenceError: "angular" is not defined. (line 2)"

thanks

Comment: try to load js without `https`.

Comment: I tried to load it directly with the file, so when I was in Bootstrap it worked well. but when I copied it on google sheets, it didn't worked. and I didn't managed to import directly the .js on my project

Comment: clarify 1) java? its not java. 2) .gs is unrelated to angular. you meant .js?

Comment: in google script, it's not .js files, it's .gs files. but it is java language

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a bit more changes for it to work, I made an example here:

- https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyFCCc_3dSLCVEjqKq49cQwafSeQe-P8Xazli6VEmE-/dev

**Angular Example GAS Structure:**

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <?!= include('js'); ?>

<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <?!= include('css'); ?>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div >


<div ng-app="gemStore">
    <div ng-controller="StoreController">
    <h1>Write here</h1>
        <input ng-model="name" ng-keyup="NameChange()">
        <h1>{{greeting}}</h1>
        <h2>{{name}}</h2>
    </div>

    </div>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Core.gs

```
 function doGet(e) {
  var t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');
  return t.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME).setTitle('Angular Example By Daniel C');
}
 function include(filename) {
      return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
          .getContent();
    }
```

js.html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>

    angular.module('gemStore', [])
      .controller('StoreController', function($scope) {
          $scope.NameChange = function () {
              $scope.greeting = "Hello " + $scope.name;
          };
      });

</script>
```

css.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style>
/*your styles here*/
</style>
```

It is not using your code but I am sure you will adapt it easily.

Thanks!